# Make infopath accept Number only

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Is there anyway for a textbox in infopath form to only accept numerical values without any back end programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Data validation` built-in as the following
Try this:

1. Double-click the field
2. Click Data Validation at the bottom of the dialog box.
3. Click Add
4. Select Does Not Match Pattern from the second drop-down box.
5. Type the following custom pattern into the third drop-down "\d*".
6. Type the message you want the user to see in the short and detailed error message fields.
7. Select Dialog Box Alert from the drop-down.
8. Click OK three times.

Ref: [Numeric only fields](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/2151.aspx)

For more details about `Data validation` check [3 Ways to validate data in InfoPath](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/infopath-basics-3-ways-validate-data-infopath.htm)

Comment: Glad to hear it's helped you, could you please upvote and set it as answer , it's the up button and true button beside my answer :) @Angeliedescalsota